# Is it normal for Mysql to take very long to import a big sql file?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Several days ago, I downloaded the Wikipedia "External Links" sql file. The external links table has three columnns: the first is an int(8) and the two others are a blob which has a url in it. I started importing the sql file, which has a size of 9.3 GB, with phpmyadmin, and it is now over 50 hours later, and the import process hasn't finished yet! There are so far over 33 million rows inserted.

Is it normal for it to take THAT long, or is there something wrong with my setup?

Note: my server is an e3-1230 with 16 GB of RAM.

TIA!

Comment: Without information about how your MySQL instance is configured it's hard to say why this would be the case. The default configuration is actually terrible.

Comment: I recommand you to use a program instead of phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin runs in a browser so its slower than for example navicat. 50 hours looks like a bug.

Comment: @tadman any pointers or links as to how to improve the configuration?

Comment: If you're using InnoDB, which you *should* be, make sure [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) is set to at least 512MB. Give it more memory if you can afford it. On a 16GB server, if it's just for your database, I'd crank it up to at least 10GB. This provides the biggest performance boost of all the various settings.

Answer (score 1):

It seems too long. This is for your reference.

Specification of my computer : 
- Windows 10 home
- Intel Core i5-3317U CPU@1.7GHz
- 6GB of RAM memory
- 750 GB 5400 RPM hard drive
- MySQL 5.7 and MySQL Workbench 6.3CE

I imported two files which were downloaded from NYC open data portal. 
NYC taxi fare.csv : 1.67 GB of the size, 11 columns, 15749228 rows.
nyc311calls.csv :   5.83 GB of the size, 53 columns, 11145686 rows

The sql script is the below
     LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/test_data/FILE_NAME' 
     INTO TABLE DB_NAME
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 ROWS;

Running time to import fare.csv : 320.706 sec (less than 6 minutes)
Running time to import nyc311calls.csv : 968 sec (about 16 minutes)